# How to include libcurl in cmake library

Tags: c++, curl, cmake, libcurl

I am creating a cpp library that has libcurl as a dependency. I would like for the user to supply the path to libcurl on their computer. What is the best way to do this?

Edit: To clarify, I am making the library on windows, but I would like for it to be cross-platform

Comment: Which platform, Linux/BSD/MSWindows? Details matter.

Comment: I would use a package manager like [Conan](https://conan.io/).

Comment: When you say you would "like for the user to supply the path to libcurl on their computer," does this mean you want different behavior from CMake's [`find_package`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_package.html) functionality or is that sufficient? Asked differently: Does `find_package(CURL REQUIRED)` not work for you?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik sorry, I updated the question

Comment: @TravisGockel I tried that but I got an error: Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description, you have to add the search path to the list of paths that cmake inspects when it tries to find a package by calling `[find_package]`

If you want to support user-defined path for linking `libcurl` shared object (`libcurl.so`), you can pass it via `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` from `cmake` command

**Usage example**

`cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=<full_path_where_curl_is_installed> -B build -S .`

*Assuming that the build artifacts will be at `build` sub-directory of main project (where the top-level `CMakeLists.txt` exists) and used cmake version is **3.16+***

If you want to embed the information at your own `CMakeLists.txt`, you can enable the path for curl as search path

**Usage example**

in your `CMakeLists.txt`, add the following line before calling `find_package` for `CURL`

`list(APPEND CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH <full_path_where_curl_is_installed>)`